# How can I align the thee spans with the width of the parent container?

Tags: html, css

Look at the picture, I have three span on the top of the "health issue", both width will be 89%, it is responsive. The challenge is that I cannot make 'ask,question,answer' width align with the health issue, especially when it's responsive.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 89%;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin: 24px auto;
}
#wrap span {
  float: left;
  padding: 19px;
}
#health_issue {
  width: 89%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <span id="wrap_a">ASK</span>
  <span id="wrap_q">QUESTION</span>
  <span id="wrap_an">ANSWER</span>
</div>
<!--wrap-->
<div style="clear:both;">

  <div id="health_issue">
    <h1>My Health Issue</h1>
    <p>Describe your health problem</p>
  </div>
  <!--health_issue-->
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I am not quite understand you, what requirement?, I am using wordpress, and try to make website.

Comment: What do you mean by "make 'ask,question,answer' width align with the health issue"?

Answer (score 0):

Your elements are currently `inline` therefore they won't respond to width changes. You can change the style of `#wrap span` as follows

```
#wrap span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
}
```

This will then put all of the elements at a 33% width depending on the parent.

This doesn't work when an element is `inline` as `<span>` tags are by default. Thus the change to `display: inline-block`

## Full Snippet

```css
#wrap {
  width: 89%;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin: 24px auto;
}
#wrap span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%
}
#health_issue {
  width: 89%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <span id="wrap_a">ASK</span>
  <span id="wrap_q">QUESTION</span>
  <span id="wrap_an">ANSWER</span>
</div>
<!--wrap-->
<div style="clear:both;">

  <div id="health_issue">
    <h1>My Health Issue</h1>
    <p>Describe your health problem</p>
  </div>
  <!--health_issue-->
</div>
```

If you're able to support [flex boxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) then you can also use the following. Flex boxes are supported on all major browser versions. Internet explorer has some issues with modern specification of it. See [can i use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox):

```css
#wrap {
  width: 89%;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin: 24px auto;
  display: flex;
}
#wrap span {
  flex-grow:1;
}
#health_issue {
  width: 89%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <span id="wrap_a">ASK</span>
  <span id="wrap_q">QUESTION</span>
  <span id="wrap_an">ANSWER</span>
</div>
<!--wrap-->
<div style="clear:both;">

  <div id="health_issue">
    <h1>My Health Issue</h1>
    <p>Describe your health problem</p>
  </div>
  <!--health_issue-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for respond, if you set the width to 32%, the third span will go to the second line when the window screen  squeeze to less than 800px.

Comment: If you run the above stack-snippet it works for sizes less than 800px. It is probably something else on the page that's a fixed size that's causing problems.